# How to convert string to int in pic controller

Tags: c, string, embedded, pic

How to convert a string to int to display on LCD. I tried using `itoa`, is not supported by compiler even after adding `<stdlib.h>`.

Here is my code:

Comment: If you're wanting to display a number on an LCD, then you don't want it to be an int. You want it to be a string of characters which represent the int. Are you really asking how to convert an int to a string?

Comment: Why would you try to use itoa(), that converts an int to a string, not a string to an int.  You need strtol() instead, which is a standard function since C89, so more likely to be available.  C99 defines atoi() also.

Comment: However, it seems that you need to fix the question and you intended to convert into to a string in any case.

Comment: @maxy What base are you in to consider 00010000 is equal to 10?

Comment: @maxy Well, isn't what I wrote under do? Or even functions Clifford mentioned? Also, please show what you've already tried.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to convert an int to a string (body of question) or string to an int (title of question). Your code makes little sense so it is impossible to tell what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>    

int stringToInt(char * s){
    int res = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
        res = (res * 10) + (s[i] - '0');
    return res;
}

int main(void){
    printf("%d\n", stringToInt("256"));
    return(0);
}
```

This won't work with number exceeding what an `int` can store though. Or just use strltol / strtoul / atoi from stdlib.h.

Answer (score 1):

Fist you can easily show string on your LCD without any conversion. 
Second, I checked itoa in MplabX it worked just fine!!

All in all this works fine:

```
int toString(char a[]) {
  int c, sign, offset, n;

  if (a[0] == '-') {  // Handle negative integers
    sign = -1;
  }

  if (sign == -1) {  // Set starting position to convert
    offset = 1;
  }
  else {
    offset = 0;
  }

  n = 0;

  for (c = offset; a[c] != '\0'; c++) {
    n = n * 10 + a[c] - '0';
  }

  if (sign == -1) {
    n = -n;
  }

  return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`iota` is supported in the xc compiler.
You had to do the following setting in MPLABx:

Project Properties / Global options and then deselect Use legacy libc